# async:false for a server request

Tags: jquery

I am posting a synchronous ajax request (knows not recommended but has one of such requirement) to a server with async:false. The concern is that no response is expected from the server to which the request is being posted. The server to which the request is being posted adds some variable to a global variable used by a third party so it doesnot send any response back to the calling function. will async:false work for such methods where no response is expected from the server or the server always have to return any value to the calling function? 
Is there any default value that the server returns in case no value is being returned from the server to the calling method? 
My requests looks like::

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
    async:false,
    url:....,
    type:...,
    success:...
    });
    return true;
    });
```

Please help out as I am new to ajax requests.

Comment: At a minimum the web server must return a HTTP status so the success or fail functions in the ajax call can be executed.

Comment: Does this mean that the web server should have a return statement with the HTTP Status or does this mean that the HTTP status will be sent by default if no other data is returned? Moreover, is the same thing expected (response expected) if we have async:true or does it behave differently in terms of returning response from web server?

Comment: What is the `dataType` you are passing in the ajax call or can the call infer it from the URL? Are you using some kind of App Server (RoR/php/ASP/JSP/whatever)? If so, what does the server code look like? `async:false` will just block all other JS execution on the client until the ajax call returns.

Comment: I am working on ASP and I am using type:json but I don't expect any response from web server as web server is not returning anything back to the calling function. I am aware that async:false will just block all other JS execution on the client until the ajax call is executed but that is fine as per the current requirement. The concern is that if web server is not returning anything to the calling function (as the web server has to update the database only), will this ajax function work?

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebug in FireFox or Developer tools in Chrome. With the network tab open on either of these, surf to the url you are calling via ajax. You should see a status code show up. Hopefully it is http code 200 which will tell the ajax call it was successful.

Comment: The httpfox shows status code 200. This means that my ajax function works and it is not necessary for web server to return any response. Moreover, this also means that HTTP status is a default response. Thanks a lot for your quick response.